# How to find the area of a function (Pseudo Voigt) using optimized parameters from lmfit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, numerical-integration, lmfit

I am trying to determine the area of a curve (peak). I was able to successfully fit the peak (data) using a Pseudo Voigt profile and a exponential background and get the fitting parameters out which agree with parameters obtained using commercial software. The issue is now trying to relate those fitted peak parameters to the area of the peak.

I could not find an simple method of using the fitted parameters to calculate the area of the peak unlike in the case with a Gaussian line shape. So I am trying to use the scipy quad function to integrate my fitted function. I know the area should be around 19,000 determined by commercial software but I am getting very large incorrect values.

The fitting works very well (confirmed by plotting...) but the calculate area is not close. After trying to plot the my psuedo_voigt_func function with the best fit values passed to it, I found that it was a much too intense peak. With that, the integration might have been correct then the error would be in how I create my peak which was by passing the fitted parameters to my psuedo_voigt_func function, in which the function was transcribed from the lmfit model website (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html). I believe I scripted the psuedo voigt function correctly but it isn't working.

```
#modules
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, LinearModel, VoigtModel, Pearson7Model, ExponentialModel, PseudoVoigtModel

from scipy.integrate import quad

#data
x = np.array([33.05, 33.1 , 33.15, 33.2 , 33.25, 33.3 , 33.35, 33.4 , 33.45, 33.5 , 33.55, 33.6 , 33.65, 33.7 , 33.75, 33.8 , 33.85, 33.9 , 33.95, 34.  , 34.05, 34.1 , 34.15, 34.2 , 34.25, 34.3 , 34.35, 34.4 , 34.45, 34.5 , 34.55, 34.6 , 34.65, 34.7 , 34.75, 34.8 , 34.85, 34.9 , 34.95, 35.  , 35.05, 35.1 , 35.15, 35.2 , 35.25, 35.3 , 35.35, 35.4 , 35.45, 35.5 , 35.55, 35.6 , 35.65, 35.7 , 35.75, 35.8 , 35.85, 35.9 , 35.95, 36.  , 36.05, 36.1 , 36.15, 36.2 , 36.25, 36.3 , 36.35, 36.4 , 36.45])

y = np.array([4569,  4736,  4610,  4563,  4639,  4574,  4619,  4473,  4488, 4512,  4474,  4640,  4691,  4621,  4671,  4749,  4657,  4751, 4921,  5003,  5071,  5041,  5121,  5165,  5352,  5304,  5408, 5393, 5544, 5625,  5859,  5851,  6155,  6647,  7150,  7809, 9017, 10967, 14122, 19529, 28029, 39535, 50684, 55730, 52525, 41356, 30015, 20345, 14368, 10736,  9012,  7765,  7064,  6336, 6011,  5806,  5461,  5283,  5224,  5221,  4895,  4980,  4895, 4852,  4889,  4821,  4872,  4802,  4928])

#model
bkg_model = ExponentialModel(prefix='bkg_') #BACKGROUND model
peak_model = PseudoVoigtModel(prefix='peak_') #PEAK model
model = peak_model + bkg_model

#parameters
pars = bkg_model.guess(y, x=x) #BACKGROUND parameters
pars.update(peak_model.make_params()) #PEAK parameters
pars['peak_amplitude'].set(value=17791.293, min=0)
pars['peak_center'].set(value=35.2, min=0, max=91)
pars['peak_sigma'].set(value=0.05, min=0)

#fitting
init = model.eval(pars, x=x) #initial parameters
out = model.fit(y, pars, x=x) #fitting

#integration part
def psuedo_voigt_func(x, amp, cen, sig, alpha): 
    sig_gauss = sig / np.sqrt(2*np.log(2))
    term1 = (amp * (1-alpha)) / (sig_gauss * np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
    term2 = np.exp(-(x-cen)**2) / (2 * sig_gauss**2)
    term3 = ((amp*alpha) / np.pi) * ( sig / ((x-cen)**2) + sig**2)
    psuedo_voigt = (term1 * term2) + term3

    return psuedo_voigt

fitted_amp = out.best_values['peak_amplitude']
fitted_cen = out.best_values['peak_center']    
fitted_sig = out.best_values['peak_sigma']    
fitted_alpha = out.best_values['peak_fraction']    

print(quad(psuedo_voigt_func, min(x), max(x), args=(fitted_amp, fitted_cen, fitted_sig, fitted_alpha)))



#output result of fit:
[[Model]]
    (Model(pvoigt, prefix='peak_') + Model(exponential, prefix='bkg_'))

[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 542
    # data points      = 69
    # variables        = 6
    chi-square         = 2334800.79
    reduced chi-square = 37060.3300
    Akaike info crit   = 731.623813
    Bayesian info crit = 745.028452

[[Variables]]
    bkg_amplitude:   4439.34760 +/- 819.477320 (18.46%) (init = 10.30444)
    bkg_decay:      -38229822.8 +/- 5.6275e+12 (14720258.94%) (init = -5.314193)
    peak_amplitude:  19868.0711 +/- 106.363477 (0.54%) (init = 17791.29)
    peak_center:     35.2039076 +/- 3.3971e-04 (0.00%) (init = 35.2)
    peak_sigma:      0.14358871 +/- 5.6049e-04 (0.39%) (init = 0.05)
    peak_fraction:   0.62733180 +/- 0.01233108 (1.97%) (init = 0.5)
    peak_fwhm:       0.28717742 +/- 0.00112155 (0.39%) == '2.0000000*peak_sigma'
   peak_height:     51851.3174 +/- 141.903066 (0.27%) == '(((1 peak_fraction)*peak_amplitude)/max(2.220446049250313e-16, (peak_sigma*sqrt(pi/log(2))))+(peak_fraction*peak_amplitude /max(2.220446049250313e-16, (pi*peak_sigma)))'

[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(bkg_amplitude, bkg_decay)      = -0.999
    C(peak_amplitude, peak_fraction) =  0.838
    C(peak_sigma, peak_fraction)     = -0.481
    C(bkg_decay, peak_amplitude)     = -0.338
    C(bkg_amplitude, peak_amplitude) =  0.310
    C(bkg_decay, peak_fraction)      = -0.215
    C(bkg_amplitude, peak_fraction)  =  0.191
    C(bkg_decay, peak_center)        = -0.183
    C(bkg_amplitude, peak_center)    =  0.183
    C(bkg_amplitude, peak_sigma)     =  0.139
    C(bkg_decay, peak_sigma)         = -0.137

#output of integration:
(4015474.293103768, 3509959.3601876567)

C:/Users/script.py:126: IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.
```

Comment: hi, I had the impression that a constant background works just fine. Any particular reason to use the exponential model? ...( -3.8e7 +/- 5.6e12 ???)

Comment: actually it turns out that there are two mistakes in your Pseud-Voigt: term2 should read: `np.exp( -(x - cen)**2  /  (2 * sig_gauss**2) )` ter3 should read `((amp*alpha) / np.pi) * ( sig / ((x - cen)**2 + sig**2) )`. Hence, twice a problem of parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I decided not to use the lmfit module and instead just write out my own equations, which I have a working script now. No particular reason for an exponential baseline contribution to the peak data as I was just trying out different ones. I settled on a quadratic for the baseline term and a Voigt function for the peak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe OP's `pseudo_voigt` is not well formatted, but does not seem to be wrong, either, There are different definitions of the `pseudo_voigt`, though. Below I implemented one from Wikipedia (link in code), which usually gives good results. Looking on the logarithmic scale, however, it is not so good with this data. I also used the complex definition to get the true Voigtusing the `Fedeeva` function like `lmfit`.

Code looks as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import wofz
from scipy.integrate import quad

def cauchy(x, x0, g):
    return 1. / ( np.pi * g * ( 1 + ( ( x - x0 ) / g )**2 ) )

def gauss( x, x0, s):
    return 1./ np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * s**2 ) * np.exp( - (x-x0)**2 / ( 2 * s**2 ) )

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_profile#Numeric_approximations
def pseudo_voigt( x, x0, s, g, a, y0 ):
    fg = 2 * s * np.sqrt( 2 * np.log(2) )
    fl = 2 * g
    f = ( fg**5 +  2.69269 * fg**4 * fl + 2.42843 * fg**3 * fl**2 + 4.47163 * fg**2 * fl**3 + 0.07842 * fg * fl**4+ fl**5)**(1./5.)
    eta = 1.36603 * ( fl / f ) - 0.47719 * ( fl / f )**2 + 0.11116 * ( f / fl )**3
    return y0 + a * ( eta * cauchy( x, x0, f) + ( 1 - eta ) * gauss( x, x0, f ) )

def voigt( x, s, g):
    z = ( x + 1j * g ) / ( s * np.sqrt( 2. ) )
    v = wofz( z ) #Feddeeva
    out = np.real( v ) / s / np.sqrt( 2 * np.pi )
    return out


def fitfun(  x, x0, s, g, a, y0 ):
    return y0 + a * voigt( x - x0, s, g )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xlist = np.array( [ 33.05, 33.1 , 33.15, 33.2 , 33.25, 33.3 , 33.35, 33.4 , 33.45, 33.5 , 33.55, 33.6 , 33.65, 33.7 , 33.75, 33.8 , 33.85, 33.9 , 33.95, 34.  , 34.05, 34.1 , 34.15, 34.2 , 34.25, 34.3 , 34.35, 34.4 , 34.45, 34.5 , 34.55, 34.6 , 34.65, 34.7 , 34.75, 34.8 , 34.85, 34.9 , 34.95, 35.  , 35.05, 35.1 , 35.15, 35.2 , 35.25, 35.3 , 35.35, 35.4 , 35.45, 35.5 , 35.55, 35.6 , 35.65, 35.7 , 35.75, 35.8 , 35.85, 35.9 , 35.95, 36.  , 36.05, 36.1 , 36.15, 36.2 , 36.25, 36.3 , 36.35, 36.4 , 36.45])
    ylist = np.array( [ 4569,  4736,  4610,  4563,  4639,  4574,  4619,  4473,  4488, 4512,  4474,  4640,  4691,  4621,  4671,  4749,  4657,  4751, 4921,  5003,  5071,  5041,  5121,  5165,  5352,  5304,  5408, 5393, 5544, 5625,  5859,  5851,  6155,  6647,  7150,  7809, 9017, 10967, 14122, 19529, 28029, 39535, 50684, 55730, 52525, 41356, 30015, 20345, 14368, 10736,  9012,  7765,  7064,  6336, 6011,  5806,  5461,  5283,  5224,  5221,  4895,  4980,  4895, 4852,  4889,  4821,  4872,  4802,  4928])

    sol, err = curve_fit( pseudo_voigt, xlist, ylist, p0=[ 35.25,.05,.05, 30000., 3000] )
    solv, errv = curve_fit( fitfun, xlist, ylist, p0=[ 35.25,.05,.05, 20000., 3000] )
    print solv
    xth = np.linspace( xlist[0], xlist[-1], 500)
    yth = np.fromiter( ( pseudo_voigt(x ,*sol) for x in xth ), np.float )
    yv = np.fromiter( ( fitfun(x ,*solv) for x in xth ), np.float )

    print( quad(pseudo_voigt, xlist[0], xlist[-1], args=tuple( sol ) ) )
    print( quad(fitfun, xlist[0], xlist[-1], args=tuple( solv ) ) )
    solvNoBack = solv
    solvNoBack[-1]  =0
    print( quad(fitfun, xlist[0], xlist[-1], args=tuple( solvNoBack ) ) )

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )

    ax.plot( xlist, ylist, marker='o', linestyle='', label='data' )
    ax.plot( xth, yth, label='pseudo' )
    ax.plot( xth, yv, label='voigt with hack' )
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    plt.legend( loc=0 )
    plt.show()
```

providing:

[image: data fit]

```
[3.52039054e+01 8.13244777e-02 7.80206967e-02 1.96178358e+04 4.48314849e+03]
(34264.98814344757, 0.00017531957481189617)
(34241.971907301166, 0.0002019796740206914)
(18999.266974139795, 0.0002019796990069267)
```

From the graph it is obvious that the `pseudo_voigt` is not very good. The integral, however, does not differ very much. Considering the fact that the fit optimises `chi**2` this is not such a big surprise, though.

Comment: Note that the fit results show, `sigma` and `gamma` are very similar. My impression is that Pseudo-Voigt functions are likely to work better if one dominates, explaining the "failure", here.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your work! This looks great and much better than I could do. I can definitely use this for my code. The only issue I see is that it's returning a larger area than expected and I think I have figured out why. This is doing an integration with a background at the baseline (y=0) however I need the peak area with respect to a baseline of the data which is why I had a exp background model included. I confirmed this with commercial software yielding areas of 34239 and 18704 (correct) for the former and latter cases. How can the background be incorporated?

Comment: @KillianTallman Check the update. I use a constant background. Subtraction is easy and gives an integral of about 19000. You could easily modify the code to use an exponential background. Cheers.

Comment: Wow, amazing! That is what I was looking for. To make it easier for me and other viewers to understand, could you add some comments or make the variable names more specific (e.g. a could be alpha or amplitude?). Mainly just need assistant with the variables in the functions (I have a good grasp already). And perhaps a little about what you did with the solvNoBack. It looks like you are setting y0 (not exactly sure what that variable represents) to zero so it is not passed to the Voigt function for integration. Any added comments would be greatly appreciated!!!!!

Comment: It might be instructive to realize that the original question has the correct answer right there in the printed results:  the area was indeed ~19000, exactly as `lmfit` reported, with some uncertainty due to details of the background used.  The answer here is not wrong, but it is much more work (and less clear) than the original posting using lmfit.

Comment: @MNewville Thanks for this insight; yes, the 19000 is reported by a third party tool, not by `lmfit`. The result here is only more work as it includes Voigt and Pseudo-Voigt plus printing and plotting. If you reduce the code to what is actually needed for the final integral, it is about the same or even shorter. Apart from the fact that I am not the biggest fan of `lmfit`  I think that going down to basic implementations is more clear, but that is personal taste.

Comment: @mikuszefski  Um, the value *is* reported by lmfit right there in the original question.  The fit report has `peak_amplitude:  19868.0711 +/- 106.363477 (0.54%) (init = 17791.29)`.  That is the area under the unit-normalized peak, which is what the original question was.   You are welcome to use `curve_fit` if you want (and have to deal with turning the covariance into uncertainties and the limitations of using an array of variables instead of Parameter objects), but please do not incorrectly say that it is not giving the correct or interpretable results, including uncertainties.

Comment: @MNewville Please read carefully: Neither did I say it provides incorrect results nor that it is non-interpretable. The amplitude equals the area if the function is correct and normalized. If pedantic, however, this is only true if one integrates from `-inf` to `inf`, which the OP does not. Moreover, there was an error in the pseudo-voigt implementation, rendering this even more complicated. Finally, I prefer `leastsq` or even `least_squares` over `curve_fit`. Whether or not data structures implemented by others are limiting me, I'll not discuss here. Cheers. tldr; All previously said holds.

Comment: @mikuszefski  You do not need to explicitly integrate (over any range) to get the area.  The "amplitude" of the peak-like lineshapes in `lmfit` are scale factors of the unit-normalized peak, and so *are* the areas.  Yes, you could write your own peak functions and explicitly integrate, but that is error-prone and is not necessary if you use the proper definitions for the lineshapes.   The OP asked how to interpret the results from a library, and your answer here is essentially "use a different library and do unnecessary steps to get an answer that is right there in the original question".

Answer (score 0):

As with the other peak-like lineshapes and models in `lmfit`, the `amplitude` parameter should give the area of that component.

For what it's worth, it's probably better to use the true Voigt function instead of the pseudo-Voigt function.