# Deconvoluting a Voigt fitting in Python to extract Lorentzian FWHM?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting, deconvolution

I've found loads of examples of how to fit a Voigt profile to spectral data but I'm wondering if there's a way to deconvolute it and specifically determine the FWHM of the Lorentzian component.
I know if you do Voigt fitting in Origin, it returns a load of data including the Gaussian and Lorentzian FWHM but I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Python.
Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on the level of accuracy you need. One solution can be using the Pseudo-Voigt approximation described on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_profile). This approximation uses a linear combination of a Gaussian and a Lorentzian instead of convolution, therefore, it is straightforward to extract the FWHM.

Comment: Well, you could make a proper fit  in Python using the implemented Feddeeva function. E.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58448766/803359)

Comment: moreover the voigt profile itself is implemented in [scipy](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.special.voigt_profile.html)

Comment: Deconvolution would mean something like...make the FFT of the peak and fit the result with the product of the Fouriertransform a Gaussian (which is a Gaussian) and the FT of the Cauchy profile  ( exp( -gamma |x| ) )...there are plenty of pitfalls if it comes to FFT, though

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Vaczi 2014 article ["A New, Simple Approximation for the Deconvolution of Instrumental Broadening in Spectroscopic Band Profiles"](http://doi.org/10.1366/13-07275).

He discussed resolving Lorentz width by removal/deconvolution of instrument-based Gauss broadening from measured Voight width/broadening. The best formula was in Eq. (10) based on Kielkopf/Olivero which results in the maximum relative error of 3.8E-3. His suggested Eq. (5b) has a maximum relative error of 1.2E-2 (1.2%) and should be avoided.